# Metadata Rejected

Tags: ios, iphone

Recently i have uploaded my app into appstore but metadata is rejected with the following reason. Please let me know clealry why they rejected and what to do now and can i upload the screenshots again.

We began the review of your app but are not able to continue because we need a demo account to fully access your app features.

Please provide demo account details in the Review Notes section of the Version Information for your app. Please ensure that the information you provide includes any data necessary to demonstrate the functionality of your app features.

While your iTunes Connect Application State shows as Metadata Rejected, we don't require a new binary to correct this issue. Please visit iTunes Connect, Manage Your Applications. Select your app, then click View Details of the desired version. Click the Edit button next to Version Information to edit the Review Notes for your app, then click "Save".

When you are done, click "Submit New Metadata" and we can resume the review of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They rejected it because you have a user-login in your app. You can provide them with demo account credentials (e.g. username & password) in the review notes section on iTunesConnect. Just follow their instructions.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, unfortunately i clicked on Submit new metadata without entering the required details. what to do now Please help me

Comment: You should be able to edit the metadata again. If not you have to wait until Apple rejects them again.

Comment: yes i have saved my metadata but it will submit to them or not?

Comment: If you pressed "submit new metadata" it will be automatically submitted. It takes some time until they will review it again, be patient.

Comment: No problem, I had the same problem with one of my apps before. Please mark a response as answer.

Answer (score 0):

As they informed, visit iTunes Connect, Manage Your Applications. Select your app, then click View Details of the desired version. Click the Edit button next to Version Information to edit the Review Notes for your app. **Provide the required demo account credentions (user name, password etc.)** there to demonstrate the functionality of your app features. That's it.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, unfortunately i clicked on Submit new metadata without entering the required details. what to do now Please help me

Comment: Please answer to my comment

Comment: what's the app status now?

Comment: you can click on the app icon, then you can see the section "Metadata and Uploads". then click on the "Edit" button and submitt again.

Comment: not click submit review button if click then your apps was been 5 to 8 day queue side , so must be wait for few day and not any new binary ipa  file upload , all metadata information must read than fill all detail

Answer (score 0):

Give the review details and your demo user name and password here

[image]